# Symfony JMSSerializer create object entity and relation entities and set

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I use api full contact service and when I have json data from service I need set in DB. I have entity ApiFullContact and relation OneToMany entity socialProfiles, because in response have many social profiles and need set data like with JMS serializer set only ApiFullContact and set relation entity, I try use Accessor then VirtualProperty but still not set socialProfiles entities, this my entities:

```
* @ExclusionPolicy("all")
*/
class ApiFullContact
{
use Timestampable;
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @Expose()
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="integer", nullable=true)
 * @Expose()
 */
protected $status;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="likelihood", type="integer", nullable=true)
 * @Expose()
 */
protected $likelihood;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="requestId", type="string", nullable=true)
 * @Expose()
 * @SerializedName("requestId")
 */
protected $requestId;

/**
 * @var \Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\CodeProfileLinks
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\CodeProfileLinks", mappedBy="apiFullContact", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @Expose()
 * @SerializedName("socialProfiles")
 * @Accessor()
 * @Type("Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\CodeProfileLinks")
 */
private $socialProfiles;
```

and relation entity

```
class CodeProfileLinks
{
use Timestampable;
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="string", nullable=true)
 * @Expose()
 */
private $url;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", nullable=true)
 * @Expose()
 */
private $type;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 * @Expose()
 */
protected $username;
```

in my action

```
     $apiFullContact = $this->get('serializer')->deserialize(
            $data,
            'Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\ApiFullContact',
            'json'
        );
```

and need set

and response from service:

```
{
"status": 200,
"likelihood": 0,
"requestId": "4076a34b-f14e-4331-a999-641be7feb2d5",
"contactInfo": {
"familyName": "Name",
"fullName": "Your Name",
"givenName": "Your"
},
"organizations": [],
"demographics": [],
"socialProfiles" : {
"twitter" : [ {
  "followers" : 1,
  "following" : 1,
  "type" : "twitter",
  "typeId" : "twitter",
  "typeName" : "Twitter",
  "url" : "https://twitter.com/Shuba_Vanya",
  "username" : "Shuba_Vanya",
  "id" : "2294488585"
} ],
"github" : [ {
  "type" : "github",
  "typeId" : "github",
  "typeName" : "Github",
  "url" : "https://github.com/shubaivan",
  "username" : "shubaivan"
} ]
},
}
```

and how set entity ApiFullContact with relation entity socialProfiles data, how to set relation entities ???

Comment: Very hard to understand ... In the json you show, the `socialProfiles`  property is correctly serialised. Do you want exclude the `socialProfiles` from json ?

Comment: Update question. No. How set entity ApiFullContact with relation entity socialProfiles data, how to set relation entities ???